# CustomeProfile class, list of key-value pair is not saving

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-profiles

```
public class KeyValue : ProfileBase
{
    public KeyValue()
    { }

    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> pair
    {
        get { return (List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>)base["pair"]; }
        set { base["pair"] = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return base["Name"] as string; }
        set { base["Name"] = value; }
    }
}
```

Whats the problem in this CustomProfile class.I am saving the list of key-value pairs but when i am accessing it show null in each pair, but it gives name correctly

Comment: define "I am saving the list"

Comment: When (which page life cycle event) are you "accessing" it?

Comment: List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> i am saving this in profile, it saved properly but when i access it , it shows null in each pair`s key and value property

Comment: I am doing this in MVC3\

Comment: could you please post the code for ProfileBase as well?

Comment: how could i , ProfileBase is an abstract base class to manage asp.net inbuilt profile system